# How do I display the featured image from an image gallery using a reference in code? (example within)

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, gallery

I've been trying to get the featured image of a post to be displayed outside of the loop for all the image thumbnails. That way, the featured image (of a product) is displayed in large and the thumbnails just below it. All the images in the (product) post are set in their own gallery of images.

Please see comment in code- the place where I'm trying to get the featured image to be displayed.

I'm sure I'm just missing something easy! Thanks!!

```
if (themedy_get_option('product_gallery')) { add_action('genesis_post_content', 'themedy_product_images', 1); }
function themedy_product_images() { ?>
    <?php 
    global $post;
    $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'numberposts' => 999, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) ); 
    if ( $images ) { ?>
<div class="twocol-one">
<?php
//How do I insert the featured image of the post over here
?>
    <div class="product_images">
        <div class="container">
            <?php
            foreach ( $images as $image ){
                $gallery_image_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full' );
                $gallery_image = $gallery_image_info[0];

                $gallery_thumb_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'Gallery Thumb' );
                $gallery_thumb = $gallery_thumb_info[0];

                $gallery_image_alt = get_post_meta($image->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ? trim(strip_tags( get_post_meta($image->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) )) : trim(strip_tags( $image->post_title ));

                echo '<a href="'.$gallery_image.'" title="'.$gallery_image_alt.'" class="fancybox" rel="single-gallery"><img src="' . $gallery_thumb . '" /></a>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I use:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

It Outputs:

```
<img width="1125" height="1500" title="6593_front" alt="6593_front" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="..../wp-content/uploads/2011/12/6593_front.jpg">
```

The image is way too big :( I need it to output with the following class..

```
class="alignnone size-large wp-image-6593"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

First, let's create a new image size. We *could* update one of the existing sites, but we'll just add a new one for experience sake. Open up your functions.php file and add the following:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'new-size', 500, 500, true ); // Cropped 
    add_image_size( 'another-size', 400, 600 ); // Not Cropped 
}
```

Now, when you upload a *new* image, a version will be saved (assuming that the original is large enough) at the size you set via add_image_size.

For the *existing* images, you'll need to generate new thumbnails. Try the following plugin: [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/).

Ok, now let's update our reference to the new size:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'new-size' ); ?>
```

And here's how to get it full sized:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' ); ?>
```

Comment: Note: I missed specifying the size at first. Be sure to try it with the size set.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you. I actually did that, but the size is HUGE. Can I set the wordpress "large" versions to be smaller sized for the posts? The 'large' and 'medium' are too big for the 2 column layout I'm using :( Thank you again

Comment: Ah ha! Give me a moment to edit my answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Give the update a try and report back.

Comment: Thank you! Ok so if I set the thumbnail sizes to be squared up like in your example, 500x500, won't that make some images (not all images are the same dimension) skewed/squashed? I could add TRUE to crop them, but cropping isn't an option unfortunately :( is there a way to say, reduce the LARGE thumbnails by 30% width and height? :)

Comment: And is there a reference to point the img src to the originally uploaded featured image, rather than wordpress's re-adjusted dimension large image? thank you!!!

Comment: @iCer - Give me a few minutes and I'll get back to you!

Comment: Ok, first, just remove the reference to "true" in add_image_size. That will just "resize", without cropping, giving you the scale effect you're after.

Comment: if you get a chance to take a look at my new issue, it would be very much appreciated! Thanks!! http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43615/displaying-a-featured-image-only-img-url-as-the-img-src