# Displaying a featured image (only img url) as the img src?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, gallery

I have the following code:

```
if (themedy_get_option('product_gallery')) { add_action('genesis_post_content', 'themedy_product_images', 1); }
function themedy_product_images() { ?>
    <?php 
    global $post;
    $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'numberposts' => 999, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) ); 
    if ( $images ) { ?>
<div class="twocol-one">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'product-400x600' ); ?>
    <div class="product_images">
        <div class="container">
            <?php
            foreach ( $images as $image ){
                $gallery_image_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full' );
                $gallery_image = $gallery_image_info[0];

                $gallery_thumb_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'Gallery Thumb' );
                $gallery_thumb = $gallery_thumb_info[0];

                $gallery_image_alt = get_post_meta($image->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ? trim(strip_tags( get_post_meta($image->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) )) : trim(strip_tags( $image->post_title ));

                echo '<a href="'.$gallery_image.'" title="'.$gallery_image_alt.'" class="fancybox" rel="single-gallery"><img src="' . $gallery_thumb . '" /></a>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Issue #1: Where it says:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'product-400x600' ); ?>
```

*I need it to say*

```
<a id="product" class="MagicZoomPlus" href=" <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?> " rel="selectors-class: Active"><img src=" <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'product-400x600' ); ?> " alt="" /></a>`
```

Where it echo's the images (large and product-400x600), I need it to only echo the img url, without all the other html that comes with it. How can i fix my above code to have it rendered the way I require?

Issue #2: Where it says:

```
echo '<a href="'.$gallery_image.'" title="'.$gallery_image_alt.'" class="fancybox" rel="single-gallery"><img src="' . $gallery_thumb . '" /></a>';
```

It is a loop of all the other images in that gallery. For each image in the loop..
*I need it to say*

```
<a class="Selector" href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?>" rel="zoom-id:product" rev="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium' ); ?>"><img src="' . $gallery_thumb . '" alt="" /></a>
```

Again, same issue as #1 where I need it to echo just the image url/src.

The way it should function is like in this example:
http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

My first attempt as per Brian's suggestion below for the featured image, works!

```
<?php
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
    $image2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'product-400x600');
?>
<?php echo '<a id="product" class="MagicZoomPlus" href="'.$image[0].'" rel="selectors-class: Active"><img src="'.$image2[0].'" alt="" /></a>'; ?>
```

**Now the question is, how do I go about this for the image gallery items?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the functions you need to be aware of:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Example sans size:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());
```

Example with size:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
echo $image[0]; //as HREF in your A tag
```

You can grab all of the gallery images as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);

$attachments = get_children( $args );

foreach($attachments as $attachment){
    //use $attachment->ID to retrieve attachment information
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'large');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference. So how does that fit in to the loop? ie: how do I know which thumbnail id is for the large, medium and small version of which image?

Comment: Thanks for the update on reference to the get_attachment_image_src! That's perfect for the featured image, but how do I do that for the loop of thumbnail images in the gallery? Sorry for not understanding the concept more easily- trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Check out the latest edit and see if that helps out.

Comment: See my attempt at the bottom of my question.. harder than I first though..

Comment: Ok I figured out that out by reading your suggestion properly :) Code is in my question - maybe you can suggest optimising it better? Just struggling now with the image gallery images..

Comment: @kaiser :) haha